# Positioning UL list after wordpress menu

Tags: css, wordpress, navigation, html-lists

In wordpress I have been able to modify the menu to show on the left hand side, but I have the social icons (facebook, twitter..etc) that i would like to show at the end of that navigation menu.  Now what I did was modify my header.php file and inserted the UL list with those icons to show at the bottom of the Menu..but as you can see it's overlapping.  Well here's an image of what's happening..and following is the code I have..

[image: this is my current issue]

```
<nav id="access" role="navigation">
    <h3 class="assistive-text"><?php _e( 'Main menu', 'twentyeleven' ); ?></h3>
    <?php /* Allow screen readers / text browsers to skip the navigation menu and get right to the good stuff. */ ?>
    <div class="skip-link"><a class="assistive-text" href="#content" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Skip to primary content', 'twentyeleven' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Skip to primary content', 'twentyeleven' ); ?></a></div>
    <div class="skip-link"><a class="assistive-text" href="#secondary" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Skip to secondary content', 'twentyeleven' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Skip to secondary content', 'twentyeleven' ); ?></a></div>
    <?php /* Our navigation menu. If one isn't filled out, wp_nav_menu falls back to wp_page_menu. The menu assigned to the primary location is the one used. If one isn't assigned, the menu with the lowest ID is used. */ ?>
    <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>
</nav><!-- #access -->
<ul class="social">
    <li><a class="youtubeicon" href="#LinkURL">youtube</a></li>
    <li><a class="facebook" href="#LinkURL">facebook</a></li>
    <li><a class="twitter" href="#LinkURL">twitter</a></li>
    <li><a class="pinterest" href="#LinkURL">pinterest</a></li>
    <li><a class="favorite" href="#LinkURL">favorite</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul.social{margin:10px 0 0 25px;}
ul.social li{float:left; padding:2px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

use the `<div style="clear:both"></div>`

```
</nav><!-- #access -->
<div style="clear:both;"></div> <--here 
<ul class="social">
```

Comment: @Andres can you provide live link ?